# Missing Marketing Icon - iOS Cordova

Tags: xcode, cordova, ios11

I get this error when uploading to AppStore:

> iOS Apps must include a 1024x1024px Marketing Icon in PNG format. Apps that do not include the Marketing Icon cannot be submitted for App Review or Beta App Review.

Comment: Oh Images.xassets -> Appicon (dumb Xcode) is where you find it

Answer (score 42):

Based on the other answers here, I believe the complete answer is:

If you did `cordova platform update ios` it will bring you the latest *stable* version, *4.4.0* as of today, which **don't know** to add the entry for the app-store icon.

So, what you need to do is:

```
cordova platform rm ios
cordova platform add ios@4.5.1
```

and add the above mentioned line into `config.xml` with a slight modification - **use a JPEG** to avoid "The App Store Icon in the asset catalog in 'appname.app' can't be transparent nor contain an alpha channel":

```
<icon height="1024" width="1024" src="icons/ios/icon-1024.jpg" />
```

> As soon as the stable version will become higher than 4.5.1, do not force that 'old' version!

To verify your iOS platform version, look for this line in `config.xml`:

```
<engine name="ios" spec="~4.5.1" />
```

> Important! from 4.5.0 and on, the plugin 'cordova-plugin-console' is not supported and not required. You must remove it in order to build successfully:

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-console
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error message: "Invalid App Store Icon. The App Store Icon in the asset catalog in 'appname.app' can't be transparent nor contain an alpha channel."

Any ideas? Our icon does contain transparent areas, we can't remove them (CI).

Comment: I can tell you what I did: I have changed my App Store icon into JPEG so that they can't complain for transparency. it worked. I'll edit my answer with this info

Comment: Note that if you use `cordova platform add ios@^4.5.1` it should continue to update to more recent versions automatically, so the comment about "forcing versions" wouldn't apply.

Comment: How can I keep the console plugin for the windows platform, while removing it from iOS platform?

Answer (score 18):

Update to latest cordova-ios version: 4.5.1 and register Marketing icon in config.xml

```
<icon height="1024" width="1024" src="icons/ios/icon-1024.png" />
```

Ref: https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/pull/337

Comment: have the same issue with phonegap. I did update cordova and phonegap, add the 1024 icon in config.xml <icon height="1024" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/1024-icon.png" width="1024" /> but still get the error. Any way to do it in XCODE?

Comment: In xCode you can just drag drop your icon at Resources>Images.xcassets>AppIcon> (App Store iOS 1024pt).

Comment: @al404IT which version of cordova-ios you are using? It should be cordova-ios@4.5.1

Comment: cordova -v return 7.0.1

Comment: No, check what is a version of cordova-ios engine you are using? Check for this tag in your config.xml <engine name="ios" spec="4.5.1"/>

Comment: <engine name="ios" spec="~4.4.0" /> how do you update that?

Comment: Change that value to "~4.5.1" and then remove ios platform and then re-add ios platform.

Comment: Be careful with transparent areas and alpha channel which are rejected on app store upload

Answer (score 1):

For me I did like this.

First, change the icon size to **1024x1024**, In **yourProject/resources/icon.png**.

Then, running this in your terminal.

```
ionic cordova plugin save
ionic cordova platform rm ios
ionic cordova platform add ios
```

Finally, IOS platform build successful and auto modifying config.xml successful.

You will see `<icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />` in your **config.xml**. Then try upload your project to AppStore again.

Answer (score 0):

Open Xcode => Drag your appstore icon into Resources/Images.xcassets/Appicon => Remove any transparency from you image => Use only letters for the name. e.g: appstore.png

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pn4RR.png)

Answer (score 0):

You may need add assets.car file witch is required by ios 11 and you can create it with xcode or online tool http://www.applicationloader.net/appuploader/icontool.php

put assets.car file as asset file or image file .