# Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

> Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args:
>   -xcconfig,/Users/zzm/Desktop/minan/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,民安-马来西亚.xcworkspace,-scheme,民安-马来西亚,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS
>   Simulator,name=iPhone
>   X,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/zzm/Desktop/minan/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/zzm/Desktop/minan/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

[image]

Before no error showing when I build IOS, after I did this [my stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46309992/missing-marketing-icon-ios-cordova/48337918#48337918)(because AppStore showing warning that have to upload a new size icon), error coming out.

**ionic plugin:**

```
com-sarriaroman-photoviewer 1.1.10 "PhotoViewer"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.5 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4 "Device"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 1.9.1 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.7.1 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-qqsdk 0.9.6 "QQSDK"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.1.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.3.0 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-wechat 2.0.0 "Wechat"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.2 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.1.8 "SocialSharing"
es6-promise-plugin 4.1.0 "Promise"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
onesignal-cordova-plugin 2.2.0 "OneSignal Push Notifications"
```

**ionic info**

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.7
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 ios 4.5.4
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    ios-deploy : 1.9.2
    Node       : v6.11.3
    npm        : 3.10.10
    OS         : macOS Sierra
    Xcode      : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

And I tried rebuild IOS also not working for my project, and still showing this error for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your screenshot of build log i see a "**duplicate symbol CDVLogger**".
This error is related to **cordova-plugin-console**.

Remove plugin console from your project and **config.xml** then retry to build , console plugin is not required on new version of cordova.

Comment: Sure thanks..I am tring now, so just remove console plugin, right?

Comment: Yes, remove console plugin, it avoid to generate duplicate of CDVLogger, on newest version of cordova CDVLogger is embedded in base cordova-ios framework.

Comment: Error solved...Thank you very much.. 
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console And I saw here also mentioned it.

Comment: but sir cordova-plugin-console is not available in our plugin list so how to fix above error?