# How can I manually fix "Missing Marketing Icon - iOS Apps must include a 1024x1024px"

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, testflight

I have the same problem as what is described here:

[Missing Marketing Icon - iOS Cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46309992/missing-marketing-icon-ios-cordova)

That is, I developed an app in Cordova/Ionic and now I want to push it to iTunes Connect so I can invite beta testers, via TestFlight, to try it. But I get this error:

Missing Marketing Icon - iOS Apps must include a 1024x1024px Marketing Icon in PNG format

Sadly, the fix described in the previous answer is not an option to us. Their suggestion:

```
cordova platform add ios@4.5.1
```

We are using a complicated mix of plugins, which have some serious version conflicts, such that we can only use version 4.4.0. We can not use version 4.5.

So I need to somehow add this image manually. I have very little experience with Xcode. Can anyone explain what it would mean to add this icon manually? What are the steps?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Target in Xcode and use an asset catalog for the App Icons source